# How to compute summation of variables in r

Tags: r, math, sum

I'm trying to compute a simple summation (to learn how these works on r and then use in a more complicate problem)in r.

This is the summation I'm trying to compute

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ln8S.jpg)

`sum_{i=1}^5 (x^i)` where `x` is from `1:5`.

basically the outcome should be either a vector composed like this `(sum(1^i),sum(2^i),sum(3^i),sum(4^i),sum(5^i))` so that later I can sum it to get the overall sum
 or automatically the sum. (equal to 5699).

The code I've tried to use is the following:

```
for(i in 1:5){
  for(x in 1:5){
  a[i] <- sum(x^(i))
  }
  }
a
```

however the outcome is this vector

```
[1]    5   25  125  625 3125
```

it's only doing the `1^5`,`2^5`,`3^5`,`4^5`,`5^5`

Any idea of how to do it?

Comment: Does this run?!There's no intialisation of a.

Comment: Yeah sorry I forgot to include the initialisation of a but there was!

Comment: `x <- 1:5; i <- 1:5; rowSums(outer(x, i, FUN='^'))`

Answer (score 1):

This solves your problem without the need for a `for`-loop but the more R-like `sapply`

```
vec <- sapply(1:5,function(x) sum(x^(1:5)))

vec
[1]    5   62  363 1364 3905


Sum <- sum(vec)

Sum
[1] 5699
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'll edit my answer. I'm so used to multi line sapplys that I always forget the short one-liner.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I imagined that there was a easier and faster way to do that

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly best to use built in functions (e.g. sapply, sum) in R because they are optimized and sometimes implemented in faster programming language such as C. For-loops on the other hand run inside R and can be very slow.

The following code should do what you asked for and may be helpful for learning purposes:

```
# initialize vector
a <- c()

for(x in 1:5) {
  # loop through all x

  # calculate sum for some x
  sum <- 0
  for(i in 1:5) {
    sum <- sum + x^i
  }
  # append result to vector a
  a <- c(a, sum)
}

print(a)
[1]    5   62  363 1364 3905
sum(a)
[1] 5699
```